Trouble connecting to Ambient Realtime API using Python
I'm trying to connect to the Ambient Realtime API using Python and the socketio library, but I'm encountering an exception that states
socketio.exceptions.ConnectionError: One or more namespaces failed to connect

Here's the relevant code snippet:
import socketio
import json
from pathlib import Path
import inspect

CURRENT_FILE_PATH = Path(inspect.getfile(lambda: None)).parent

LOG_FILE = CURRENT_FILE_PATH / "data.log"

with open(CURRENT_FILE_PATH / "AUTH.json") as fd:
    auth = json.load(fd)
    
sio = socketio.Client()

endpoint = f'https://rt2.ambientweather.net/?api=1&applicationKey={auth["AMBIENT_APPLICATION_KEY"]}'

@sio.event
def connect():
    print('Connected to the Socket.IO server')

@sio.event
def disconnect():
    print('Disconnected from the Socket.IO server')

@sio.event
def subscribed(data):
    print('Subscribed event received:')
    print(data)

# Connect to the Socket.IO server
b = sio.connect(endpoint)

api_keys = [auth["AMBIENT_API_KEY"]]
sio.emit('command', {'command': 'subscribe', 'apiKeys': api_keys})

sio.wait()

Ideally if I can get past the intial connection, I should be able to subscribe to the realtime data being sent.

Ended up not using python-socketio, but websockets instead. I'm not sure how I missed the helper section, but in the end, I utilized this example code for websocket from the Python asyncio helper module repo.
from __future__ import annotations

import logging
from typing import Any
import asyncio

from aioambient import Websocket
from aioambient.errors import WebsocketError

import json
from pathlib import Path
import inspect

CURRENT_FILE_PATH = Path(inspect.getfile(lambda: None)).parent

LOG_FILE = CURRENT_FILE_PATH / "data.log"

with open(CURRENT_FILE_PATH / "AUTH.json") as fd:
    auth = json.load(fd)
"""Run an example script to quickly test."""



_LOGGER = logging.getLogger()

API_KEY = auth["AMBIENT_API_KEY"]
APP_KEY = auth["AMBIENT_APPLICATION_KEY"]


def print_data(data: dict[str, Any]) -> None:
    """Print data as it is received.

    Args:
    ----
        data: The websocket data received.

    """
    _LOGGER.info("Data received: %s", data)


def print_goodbye() -> None:
    """Print a simple "goodbye" message."""
    _LOGGER.info("Client has disconnected from the websocket")


def print_hello() -> None:
    """Print a simple "hello" message."""
    _LOGGER.info("Client has connected to the websocket")


def print_subscribed(data: dict[str, Any]) -> None:
    """Print subscription data as it is received.

    Args:
    ----
        data: The websocket data received.

    """
    _LOGGER.info("Client has subscribed: %s", data)


async def main() -> None:
    """Run the websocket example."""
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

    websocket = Websocket(APP_KEY, API_KEY)

    websocket.on_connect(print_hello)
    websocket.on_data(print_data)
    websocket.on_disconnect(print_goodbye)
    websocket.on_subscribed(print_subscribed)

    try:
        await websocket.connect()
    except WebsocketError:
        _LOGGER.exception("There was a websocket error")
        return

    while True:
        _LOGGER.info("Simulating some other task occurring...")
        await asyncio.sleep(5)


asyncio.run(main())

With this, I can obtain real-time data in one-minute intervals
Output example:
INFO:root:Simulating some other task occurring...
INFO:aioambient:Received packet MESSAGE data 2["data",{"tempf":74.4,"heatindexf":72.9,"dateutc":1718640900000,"densityaltitudeft":2134,"humidity":45,"baromabsin":29.08,"dewPoint":51.66,"tz":"America/New_York","date":"2024-06-17T16:15:00.000Z","macAddress":"XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX"}]
INFO:aioambient:Received event "data" [/]
INFO:aioambient:Watchdog triggered - sleeping for 900 seconds
INFO:root:Data received: {'tempf': 74.4, 'heatindexf': 72.9, 'dateutc': 1718640900000, 'densityaltitudeft': 2134, 'humidity': 45, 'baromabsin': 29.08, 'dewPoint': 51.66, 'tz': 'America/New_York', 'date': '2024-06-17T16:15:00.000Z', 'macAddress': 'XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX'}
INFO:root:Simulating some other task occurring...
INFO:root:Simulating some other task occurring...
INFO:root:Simulating some other task occurring...
INFO:aioambient:Received packet PING data 
INFO:aioambient:Sending packet PONG data 
INFO:root:Simulating some other task occurring...
INFO:root:Simulating some other task occurring...
INFO:root:Simulating some other task occurring...
INFO:root:Simulating some other task occurring...
INFO:root:Simulating some other task occurring...
INFO:aioambient:Received packet PING data 
INFO:aioambient:Sending packet PONG data 
INFO:root:Simulating some other task occurring...
INFO:root:Simulating some other task occurring...
INFO:root:Simulating some other task occurring...
INFO:root:Simulating some other task occurring...
INFO:aioambient:Received packet MESSAGE data 2["data",{"tempf":74.4,"heatindexf":72.7,"dateutc":1718640960000,"densityaltitudeft":2134,"humidity":44,"baromabsin":29.08,"dewPoint":51.05,"tz":"America/New_York","date":"2024-06-17T16:16:00.000Z","macAddress":"XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX"}]
INFO:aioambient:Received event "data" [/]
INFO:aioambient:Watchdog triggered - sleeping for 900 seconds
INFO:root:Data received: {'tempf': 74.4, 'heatindexf': 72.7, 'dateutc': 1718640960000, 'densityaltitudeft': 2134, 'humidity': 44, 'baromabsin': 29.08, 'dewPoint': 51.05, 'tz': 'America/New_York', 'date': '2024-06-17T16:16:00.000Z', 'macAddress': 'XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX'}
INFO:root:Simulating some other task occurring...

